(Python) AttributeError: 'TestOne' object has no attribute 'driver'
I'm facing a challenge with learning Python Selenium.
1.I have one conftest file:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
 def setup():
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.maximize_window()
     driver.implicitly_wait(5)
     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
     driver.get("myURL")

     yield driver

     driver.quit()

2.Then i have this BaseClass
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    driver: WebDriver

3.Then I have this LoginPage File
class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    email_field = (By.ID, "email")

    def get_email_field(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.email_field)

4.Then i have this test file
class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_login(self):
        login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        email_field = login_page.get_email_field()
        email_field.send_keys("example@blah.blah")

So the problem is when i run the test error appears saying this:
self = <tests.test_login.TestOne object at 0x000002840D977CE0>

    def test_login(self):
        login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        AttributeError: 'TestOne' object has no attribute 'driver'

Chat GPT says that it shuld workXD

Looks like you are not assigning TestOne.driver anywhere, then you deref it in test_login. The initialization code for your webdriver shoud go into a constructor of either your LoginPage, or your TestOne, as TestOne seemingly attempts to pass it into the constructor of LoginPage.
